# Java two for outer for loops with two inner for loops that add to a string and the first one doesn't do anything

Tags: java, loops

```
public static void diamondOfAsterisks(int numOfRows){
   String diamondStr="";

   for (int row = 1; row == (numOfRows/2+1); row++){
       for (int space = numOfRows; space < row; space--){
           diamondStr += " ";
       }
       for (int stars = 1; stars >= (2 * row) - 1; stars++){
           diamondStr+= "*";
       }
       diamondStr+="\n";
    }

   for (int row = numOfRows/2 ; row >= 1; row--){
       for (int space = numOfRows; space > row; space--){
           diamondStr += " ";
       }
       for (int stars = 1; stars <= (2 * row)-1; stars ++){
           diamondStr += "*";
       }
       diamondStr += "\n";
   }
   System.out.print(diamondStr);
```

I'm writing a Java program to create a diamond made out of asterisks. The code above is based on pseudocode provided to me. However, in NetBeans 8.0.1 with Java 8u25 (doubt it's an issue of IDE but just in case), the first for loop doesn't seem to add anything to diamondStr. What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first for loop, the condition to execute the loop is row == (numOfRows/2+1), which I think is a mistake
It should be changed to row <= (numOfRows/2+1)

Comment: No the condition to terminate the loop is row == (numOfRows/2+1). The syntax of a for loop is for (initialization; termination condition; increment){statements}

Comment: No, it's not, please take a look at here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm, if it's true, it will execute the for loop

Comment: OK I see what you're saying, but when I make this change it seems to run an infinite loop.

Comment: in the 2nd for inner loop, your condition is also incorrect, "stars >= (2 * row) - 1" will always evaluate to true if row = 1, no matter what value stars is

Comment: I now see what you mean, and the same issue was in the two nested loops in the first for loops. Not sure how I got confused because this is far from my first for loop, but thank you for showing me the error of my ways. I would upvote your answer but my reputation isn't high enough apparently.

Comment: you are welcome, you can click the tick below the upvote to accept the answer if you think it helps to solve your problem